# Is it distracting to have toolbar-like box at the bottom of the page like cnet.com?

Tags: ui-design

I am designing a web page for playing some movies. I want user to concentrate on the video player. to achieve this goal, I thought I remove other elements and put them in a toolbar at the bottom of the page. by clicking controls at this toolbar, a window would appear at the top of this toolbar, and a form, or relating videos or anything else would be in it.just like what cnet.com has.

Is it a good idea ( from UI design point of view)? Is it a good solution for me to achieve my goal? any other idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toolbar idea sounds good, I would hide then show the toolbar when a user moves the mouse like most video players running in full screen. Open Windows Media Player, set to full screen and leave mouse to idle for a few seconds. You'll notice it disappears and then reappears when you move the mouse again.

This should be fairly easy to achieve with jQuery, let me know if you need a solution.

Comment: Hey, I don't mean the video controls. video player is just like what youtube has. I want to add these controls to the toolbar: Flag, like/dislike, embed, share etc.
and when user scrolls down to see comments, this toolbar would disappear.the toolbar would sticks to the bottom of visible area or window.

Comment: In that case - you can place a div at the bottom of the page (using position: static/absolute; bottom: 0) and then listen to the window.scroll event to hide it when the user scrolls.

Comment: I implemented it. I just want to know is it a good idea or not. thank you for your response.